# error contract identify

Tags: solidity, web3.py

abi:

```
[
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs":[
            {
                "internalType":"string",
                "name":"name",
                "type":"string"
            },
            {
                "internalType":"address",
                "name":"owner",
                "type":"address"
            },
            {
                "internalType":"uint256",
                "name":"duration",
                "type":"uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType":"string",
                "name":"suffix",
                "type":"string"
            },
            {
                "internalType":"address",
                "name":"resolver",
                "type":"address"
            },
            {
                "internalType":"address",
                "name":"addr",
                "type":"address"
            },
            {
                "internalType":"bytes32",
                "name":"refCode",
                "type":"bytes32"
            }
            ],
            "name":"directRegister",
            "type": "function"
    }
]
```

code:

```
tx = contract.functions.directRegister("asokasoaso1k1saa", address_wallet, _deadline, "zk", address_wallet, address_wallet, b'').build_transaction({
    'from': address_wallet,
    'value': web3.to_wei(0.0027, 'ether'),
    'nonce': nonce,
    'maxFeePerGas': 0,
    'maxPriorityFeePerGas': 0,
    'gas': 0
})
```

The problem is solved either in duration, or in bytes. I can't figure out what error. Help me pls...

upd. Error:

> Could not identify the intended function with name `directRegister`,
> positional arguments with type(s)
> `str,address,int,str,address,address,bytes` and keyword arguments with
> type(s) `{}`. Found 1 function(s) with the name `directRegister`:
> ['directRegister(string,address,uint256,string,address,address,bytes32)']
> Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.

Comment: Seems like the arguments type are not a match, can you explicitly send a `uint` and `bytes32` instead of an `int` and `bytes` arguments?

Comment: @JulissaDC how to send them with python? After all, int and bytes right, isn't it?